# Convert Array into JSON String in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, json

I have a simple array that looks like this:

```
{"image_01.jpg","image_02.jpg","image_03.jpg"}
```

I need to format it into this:

```
[{"small":"image_01.jpg","big":"image_01.jpg"},{"small":"image_02.jpg","big":"image_02.jpg"}, {"small":"image_03.jpg","big":"image_03.jpg"}]
```

I am very new to ASP.NET C#, I've been trying the examples here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx but I am not sure how to implement them into my array.

Comment: it's not exactly a multidimensional array, it looks more like an array of objects created from an array of strings

Comment: Thanks, I updated the title of my question.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/516068/C-plusConvertplusmultidimensionalplusarrayplusto).

Comment: Is the first array a C# array? If so then it should be written as `{ "image_01.jpg", "image_02.jpg", "image_03.jpg" }` or even `new[] { "image_01.jpg", "image_02.jpg", "image_03.jpg" }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to import the `System.Linq` and `System.Web.Script.Serialization` namespaces and then use the following code:

```
var array = new string[] { "image_01.jpg", "image_02.jpg", "image_03.jpg" };
var newArray = array.Select(x => new { small = x, big = x }).ToArray();

var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var json = serializer.Serialize(newArray);
```